# How to make an animated bash shell prompt for the terminal?

Tags: bash, animation, terminal, command-prompt, ubuntu-14.04

I want to make an animated curser prompt in the terminal(Ubuntu 14.04),
so i make this script:

```
while [ : ]
do
    echo -ne '|\r'
    sleep 0.3
    echo -ne '/\r'
    sleep 0.3
    echo -ne '一\r'
    sleep 0.3
    echo -ne '\\ \r'
    sleep 0.3
    echo -ne '|\r'
    sleep 0.3
    echo -ne '$\r'
    sleep 0.3
done
```

But when i put it in the .bashrc ps1 `~/animated-prompt.sh &` it make a text distortion and every thing i write is overridden by the `\r` character.
[image]

so Is there anyway to make this work ?
(IDK, like putting the script to another process thread other than the one that the terminal is working on)

Comment: I also think the question is ok on stackoverflow. It would be off-topic on askubuntu

Comment: can you show how exactly you are calling it, i.e. the line where you add it to PS1?

Comment: well i wrote the command up there but you didn't read well.
`~/animated-prompt.sh &`
but i don't put it in the ps1 i just put it at the end of the .bashrc file.
I tried to put it in the ps1 but this make the prompt disappear as this command contain `&` that make it run in the background.
so i didn't figure it yet, but if the animation problem is solved then i will figure this problem out.
and about how i put it in the ps1 `\[$(~/animated-prompt.sh &)` at the end and before the ending ' of the ps1

Comment: You cannot. `PS1` is a variable containing a single string, and `bash` does not display the prompt until that string is complete. The shell does not allow you to continuously rewrite the prompt once it is displayed.

Comment: That is why i put it at the end of the .bashrc file, but still the prompt didn't have the focus the cursor keep following the the printed character and erasing back to the head of the line so i want a solution to this problem or it also have no solution ?

Answer (score 2):

save and restore cursor position instead of \r. Move to required column location where you want animation between saving and restoring cursor position.

For cursor movement refer http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

modified script:

```
s="\033[s"
u="\033[u"

# Position of column
# As per my command prompt, i want 15th column( so 14C)
pos="\033[1000D\033[14C"
while [ : ]
do
    eval echo -ne '$s$pos\|$u'
    sleep 0.3
    eval echo -ne '$s$pos/$u'
    sleep 0.3
    eval echo -ne '$s$pos一$u'
    sleep 0.3
    eval echo -ne '$s$pos\\\\$u'
    sleep 0.3
    eval echo -ne '$s$pos\|$u'
    sleep 0.3
    eval echo -ne '$s$pos\$$u'
    sleep 0.3
done

[root@hello ~]|
```

As you were using, it works with last line in .bashrc

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this man it's so close, but what if i want this script to be in a single place and no to move with me ?
here is what i mean:http://www.mediafire.com/view/r2s4w3saqdtyf77/naruto@naruto-Inspiron-N5110_~_013.png

Comment: @BlackBlock Modified script. You have to calculate your column location and modify 14C as per it. I had assumed whatever command you use will not exceed 1000 columns (so 1000D).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -ne '一\r'
#         ^
#         |
#         \--- problem
```

This character should be a [hyphen](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm), but is actually something called
[CJK Ideograph, First](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4e00/index.htm)

Comment: Did u try this script @Steven Pennt
this is a character that is working nicer than the hyphen. this character has nothing to do with my problem here and the script works well.
i just need to get the cursor focus off this script to start writing a command in the terminal as everything i write get erased by my script.